# Socket for IPV4 mapped to IPV6

Tags: sockets, posix, ipv6, ipv4

What socket family should be used for an IP that looks as follows and it is IP4 mapped to IPV6 as far as I know:

`::ffff:171.167.66.44`

AF_INET or AF_INET_6

Any useful documentation would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ...

> `::ffff:171.167.66.44`

... is an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address.  It conveys an IPv4 address in IPv6 format, and the *address family* is thus `AF_INET6`.  That is how you must configure a socket that you will connect to such an address.

This is useful primarily for a dual-stack machine.  It must understand the IPv6-formatted address, and it must communicate with the specified endpoint via IPv4.

Here is a discussion over on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/a/1102261.

Here is what IBM has to say about it in the zOS docs: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=addresses-ipv4-mapped-ipv6.